# How to square each element in 2D list using map function python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a 2D list:

```
list1 = [[2,3,4], [3,2]]
```

I tried:

```
print( list(map(lambda x :(x**2), arr1 )))
```

but it gives error

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

How can I loop inside a map...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two maps:

```
list1 = [[2,3,4], [3,2]]
print(list(map(lambda x :list(map(lambda y: (y**2), x)), list1 )))
```

It gives the following output

> ```
>  [[4, 9, 16], [9, 4]]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is cleaner with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list1 = [[2,3,4], [3,2]]
list1 = [[i ** 2 for i in sublist] for sublist in list1]
print(list1)
# [[4, 9, 16], [9, 4]]
```

We iterate through the `sublist`s  of `list1`, and for each element in each sublist, we apply the transform -- squaring the number in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a single map and a single list comprehension is the most readable.

```
list1 = [[2, 3, 4], [3, 2]]
square = lambda x: x**2
squared = [list(map(square, sublist)) for sublist in list1]
```

Comment: Change to `list(map(square, sublist))` to get a `list` rather than a `map` object

Comment: @costaparas Good point, thank you. It's needed if they want to access elements by index. For iteration it would have behaved the same, but we don't know how OP plans to use that list.

Comment: Good point @guimoute, +1 for a good balance between `map` and list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this code:

```
list1 = [[2,3,4], [3,2]]
def power(my_list):
    return [ x**2 for x in my_list[i] ]
list=[]  
for i in range(len(list1)):
    sublist = power(list1)
    list.append(sublist)
print(list)
```

In fact, in this code, you can adjust your power by using the function and changing it.(x ** 3 or x ** 4 and etc).

Comment: There are a few issues here: (1) Its not good practice to use builtin typenames as variable names (e.g. `list` => `list2` or `result_list`). (2) This approach seems to use `i` inside the `power()` function, which can lead to bugs in larger programs. (3) You can iterate through using `for sublist in list1` and then pass `sublist` to `power()` -- which is cleaner and avoids re-using `i` across functions (the `power` function shouldn't need the whole of `list1`, just the current `sublist`).